# Disable TITUS in Outlook using Powershell

Tags: php, email, powershell, outlook, add-on

I am successfully sending mail with my PowerShell script through Outlook. The only problem I am facing is that I need to set the classification in TITUS (add-on) whenever I am sending mail. I need to disable the TITUS add-on in Outlook. Does anyone know how to disable the TITUS add-on with PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

The [COMAddIns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870066(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Application class returns a COMAddIns collection that represents all the Component Object Model (COM) add-ins currently loaded in Microsoft Outlook. So, you can find the required one and set the Loaded property to false to get it unloaded programmatically at runtime.